# Is this the right usage of using?

Tags: c#, using

I am not sure how to use using statement correct.

I try like this:

```
[HttpDelete("{ClubId}", Name = "DeleteOpenings_Club")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteClub_IsOpening([FromRoute] string ClubId)
{
        using (_db_ClubIsOpen)
        {
            var result = _db_ClubIsOpen.ClubIsOpen_TBL.Where(x => x.FK_Club == ClubId);

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                _db_ClubIsOpen.ClubIsOpen_TBL.Remove(item);
            }

            _db_ClubIsOpen.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
}
```

Comment: no is my DBContext i work with EF6

Comment: What is `_db_ClubIsOpen`? where did it come from? what is the expected lifetime? I would *not* assume that your controller method is meant to be disposing something that *it didn't create*, so... who did create it? lifetime management is complex, and we don't have all the context here

Comment: Then you probably don't want `using` - it's just syntactic sugar, `using(X){ ... }` is translated to `X; try { ... } finally {X.Dispose()}`

Comment: `_db_ClubIsOpen` almost sounds like it would be a `bool`, to be honest.

Comment: I check it and yes is implement IDisposable @Llama

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen "syntacitc sugar" is the keyword for me..

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it absolutely is NOT syntactic sugar in C#. To answer OPs question, most likely the answer is No. You wouldn't want to dispose of a member object within a function and your using statement should be where you create the object as well.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson Fair, what would be the correct way of describing "gets lowered to the same IL as ..."?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you wouldn't say that because it's not correct. There is no `try/catch/finally` block that's created automatically when you use `using`. The using statement helps with garbage collection, for disposable interfaces, but it does not load a try/catch for you.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson [SharpLab seems to think there is](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEB0ARAhgF0wblhAGZkxEBhRAb1kTuRJABZEBZACgEprb6+FE7AG6YATomwBbAA6IAvIgB2AUwDuiLLgAqmAEYAbZV068+dGjDP0AvqcS2Y1oA==). Note that Mathias never said that it created a `catch` block.

Comment: @Lawrence `using` *absolutely* generates a `try`/`finally`; this is formally documented in the language specification §13.14 (ECMA 334); additionally, `using` has *no relation whatsoever* directly to GC

Comment: I was hung up on the `catch` part, but I see now that wasn't in the original comment - my b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` is tied into lifetime management, which is a complex question.

Usually, the usage of `using` you're deploying here would be for things that *your method owns*; for example, here:

```cs
using (var dbContext = new DbContext(whatever))
{
    // some code
}
```

(or just `using var dbContext = new DbContext(whatever);` in recent C# versions)

In the above, *we are clearly creating the thing*, so it is *our job to make sure that it gets disposed*, which is happening thanks to the `using`.

However, in the example in the question, it isn't clear what `_db_ClubIsOpen` is, or what the lifetime is, or who owns it. By default, I would *absolutely not* assume that a method is responsible for taking ownership of an arbitrary field, so I would *not* expect to use `using` here, in the sense of `using (_someField)` as shown in the question. Instead, I would expect *either* some DI/IoC framework to deal with that (if it is being injected), or I would expect the type to implement `IDipsosable`, and deal with disposing the field *in `Dispose()`*.

Answer (score 0):

From the [C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement):

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of IDisposable objects. Beginning in C# 8.0, the using statement ensures the correct use of IAsyncDisposable objects.
>
> ```cs
> string manyLines=@"This is line one
> This is line two
> Here is line three
> The penultimate line is line four
> This is the final, fifth line.";
>
> using (var reader = new StringReader(manyLines))
> {
>     string? item;
>     do {
>         item = reader.ReadLine();
>         Console.WriteLine(item);
>     } while(item != null);
> }
> ```

The `using` statement allows you to limit the scope of IDisposable objects and streamline their disposal. Typically you would declare the IDisposable object within the statement of the `using` structure and use it within the body.

Comment: I think everything in here is *true*, but that *at the same time*: it doesn't really help answer whether the code in the question is correct/incorrect

Comment: Yeah I realize that now :/ I was hoping it would steer OP in the right direction but your answer fleshed that out much better. Still trying to figure out how best to answer questions on SO